# Automatic Links clickable new window in PHP print

Tags: php

How to make links clickable in this php print code.I have tried add some links in details it just show them in plain text.I want them to be clickable new window link automatically

Below is my my code:

```
<?php print $details; ?>
```

like i add details like this "visit http://facebook.com please"
so i want "http://facebook.com" to be clickable.

Comment: add target="_blank" on ur <a> tag

Comment: <textarea name="details" rows="3" cols="125" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Enter Details" id="inputid" ></textarea> 

This is code in my admin.php where i add details

Comment: U need ckeditor if u have textarea

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<?php
   $details = '<a href="http://facebook.com">my link </a>';
    echo  $details; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php $details = "<a href='http://www.facebook.com'>http://facebook.com</a>"; ?>
<?php print $details; ?>
```

Comment: no its not like this! i access my admin.php and then add details

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean

Comment: <textarea  name="details" rows="3" cols="125" maxlength="1000"  placeholder="Enter Details" id="inputid" ></textarea>

This is code in my admin.php where i add details

Comment: yes! it should be clicable and link should open in new window.

Comment: Then you have to use javascript for this.. you cant do in php... because php cannot handle browser events

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl/ 
This is the jquery plugin which picks the url and append clickable link to it